# Is it possible to hide/filter api response properties based on user role in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rbac

Is it possible to filter out the api response json properties based on user role (rbac) in nodejs without using a for loop?

For example I have this returning from an api endpoint

```
User: {
  name: string,
  email: string,
  address: string,
  dateOfBirth: string,
  gender: string
}
```

And I only want roleA to receive the fields `name` and `gender`, and roleB to receive the fields `name`, `email`, `gender` and `address` in the response json.

Example:

```
app.get('/users', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    users = getUsers();
    res.send(users);
});
```

Is it possible to hide certain properties of the user object based on the role that is calling this endpoint?

Are there any rbac libraries that can achieve this or any way to achieve this without looping through and checking each field? I've looked into casbin and casl but it seems like they do not have any rbac filtering on the data attribute level.

Comment: Can you share your current API code? I don't think it requires a library.

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL may help you.But it need to refactor the api server.Here is the introduction: https://graphql.org/